# Devise sign out route hitting the UsersController rather than SessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am running into an issue when attempting to sign out in a test.  Signing in works as expected.  My test has:

```
p "sign in URL: #{path + api_user_session_path}"
post (path + api_user_session_path), params: { unlock: encrypted_unlock }
```

and in my terminal I can see:

```
"sign in URL: http://api.example.com/api/users/sign_in"
Started POST "/api/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-12-06 15:36:51 -0500
   (3.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by API::SessionsController#create as JSON
```

However when I attempt to sign out, it is not being processed by the API::SessionsController.  Here's the test:

```
p "sign out url: #{path + destroy_api_user_session_path}"
delete (path + destroy_api_user_session_path)
```

But in my terminal I get an error:

```
"sign out url: http://api.example.com/api/users/sign_out"
Started DELETE "/api/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-12-06 15:36:51 -0500
  
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'destroy' could not be found for API::UsersController
```

For some reason it's using the `UsersController` but I don't understand why.  I've added `devise_for :users` to my `routes.rb` file.

Any idea what's going on?

`routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    ...
    devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'api/sessions' }
    ...
  end
end
```

I've done my best to include relevant routes:

```
                              new_api_user_session GET       /api/users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                      api/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
                                  api_user_session POST      /api/users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                      api/sessions#create {:format=>:json}
                          destroy_api_user_session DELETE    /api/users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                     api/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}
                             new_api_user_password GET       /api/users/password/new(.:format)                                                                 api/passwords#new {:format=>:json}
                            edit_api_user_password GET       /api/users/password/edit(.:format)                                                                api/passwords#edit {:format=>:json}
                                 api_user_password PATCH     /api/users/password(.:format)                                                                     api/passwords#update {:format=>:json}
                                                   PUT       /api/users/password(.:format)                                                                     api/passwords#update {:format=>:json}
                                                   POST      /api/users/password(.:format)                                                                     api/passwords#create {:format=>:json}
                      cancel_api_user_registration GET       /api/users/cancel(.:format)                                                                       api/registrations#cancel {:format=>:json}
                         new_api_user_registration GET       /api/users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                      api/registrations#new {:format=>:json}
                        edit_api_user_registration GET       /api/users/edit(.:format)                                                                         api/registrations#edit {:format=>:json}
                             api_user_registration PATCH     /api/users(.:format)                                                                              api/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                                                   PUT       /api/users(.:format)                                                                              api/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                                                   DELETE    /api/users(.:format)                                                                              api/registrations#destroy {:format=>:json}
                                                   POST      /api/users(.:format)                                                                              api/registrations#create {:format=>:json}
                        accept_api_user_invitation GET       /api/users/invitation/accept(.:format)                                                            api/invitations#edit {:format=>:json}
                        remove_api_user_invitation GET       /api/users/invitation/remove(.:format)                                                            api/invitations#destroy {:format=>:json}
                           new_api_user_invitation GET       /api/users/invitation/new(.:format)                                                               api/invitations#new {:format=>:json}
                               api_user_invitation PATCH     /api/users/invitation(.:format)                                                                   api/invitations#update {:format=>:json}
api_users GET       /api/users(.:format)                                                                              api/users#index {:format=>:json}
                                                   POST      /api/users(.:format)                                                                              api/users#create {:format=>:json}
                                          api_user GET       /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                          api/users#show {:format=>:json}
                                                   PATCH     /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                          api/users#update {:format=>:json}
                                                   PUT       /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                          api/users#update {:format=>:json}
                                                   DELETE    /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                          api/users#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

There are no other routes related to Devise or sessions.

Comment: I added the relevent route

Comment: Add the output of `rails routes`

Comment: I've added the relevent output

Comment: Huh, weird, you're SURE they're in that order? With `DELETE /api/users/:id` AFTER `DELETE /api/users/sign_out`? That really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: smh.  That was the culprit.  There was a group of User routes I missed